# How to pass Parameters in Ruby for Google App Script

Tags: ruby, google-apps-script

I have the following script in Google Apps:

```
function createSpreadsheet(environment, timestamp) { 
  Logger.log(environment);
  var folders = DriveApp.getFoldersByName(environment); 
  while (folders.hasNext()) {
   var folder = folders.next();
  }  

  var testName = timestamp + ".test_" + environment;
  Logger.log(testName);

  var file = {
    "title": testName,
    "mimeType": "application/vnd.google-apps.spreadsheet",
    "parents": [
      {
        "id": folder.getId()
      }
    ] 
  };

  Drive.Files.insert(file);
  var allFiles = folder.getFilesByName(testName);
  var files = {};
  while (allFiles.hasNext()) {
   var file = allFiles.next();
   return file.getId();
  } 

}
```

and from Ruby code I am performing the following call

```
request = Google::Apis::ScriptV1::ExecutionRequest.new
    request.function = 'createSpreadsheet'
    request.parameters = [environment.to_s ,timestamp.to_s ]
```

But it is not working and I get error during the execution of the script:

```
Script error message: Cannot call method "getId" of undefined.
```

What I am doing wrong ? that parameters are a simple strings

Thanks a lot

Comment: The error is in your script, as the error message says. You're trying to call `getId()` on `folder`, but `folder` is undefined when you try and call it.

Comment: Yes but it happens because the script cannot receive the name of the folder(environment) If I modified the script to use 
function createSpreadsheet() { 
  environment = "something";
  timestamp = "something";
....}

Using this it woked but I need to send the paramters from ruby

Answer (score 0):

It was my fault I forgot publishing my last change in the script